# Set TimeZone in to jqwidgets datetimeinput

Tags: jquery

Hi I am using jqwidgets datetimeinput  .
It is taking the input as GMT time .
It converting that GMt time in to desktop timezones timezone.
I want to stop that conversion.If possible I want to insert my own timezone in to jqwidgets datetimeinput .
How can I achieve that

Answer (score 0):

You could try overriding the Date object's default time zone:

```
Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset = function () {return -120;};
```